# How to pass multiple parameters for executable path in the Process Task (SSIS)?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, executeprocesstask

How to pass multiple parameters for executable path in the Process Task (SSIS)?

I will have to pass two Input Parameters.

1. Variable1  = Executable file
2. Variable2 =  String Variable as an input for the execution file

In the Execute Process Task Editor >> Process  >>
Arguments >>  `@[User::Variable1] + "" + @[User::Variable2]`

Comment: I think that you have a good answer on that. Why not accepting it??

Comment: @goofyui did you try my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You must assign an expression to achieve that:

1. Double Click on the execute process task
2. Go to Expression Tab
3. Select the `Executable` property and click on the button shown on the right side of the line
4. In the expression builder select the variable `@[User::Variable1]`
5. Add a new expression line and select the `Arguments` property
6. In the expression builder select the variable `@[User::Variable2]`

[image]